# IE 6 z-index and position: fixed; issue

Tags: html, css

Here is an issue i was trying to solve for sometime now! I looked all around for solutions, but couldnt find one. To begin with here is how my html is structured(just the skeletal framework) -

```
<body>
  <div class="header"> </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
  <a href="/some.html"><div class="feedback_div"></div></a>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

Now my **.feedback** div has been **positioned** to **fixed** and given `top: 40%;` and `right: 0;` and z-index too(ofcourse). While this work fine in all browsers as usual IE 6 messes it up. So in order to replicate its effects on IE 6 i got this solution -

```
/* IE 6 only */
* .feedback_div
{
    z-index: 9998;
    position: absolute;
    top: expression( (( t=document.documentElement.scrollTop) ? t: document.body.scrollTop) +'px');
    right: -140px;
}
* #content-wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
* #footer-wrapper
{
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
}
* html 
{
overflow: auto;
}
* html body 
{
height: 100%; /* required */
}
/* END: IE 6 only */
```

But **problem** now is that, while the the **.feedback** div follows you as you scroll, when it reaches the **.footer** div, the feedback div goes behind it. I tried playing around with the z-index but nothing worked.

Now i know that the Ideal solution would be to re-structure the html such that the **.feedback** div is child to `<body>`. But i'm not looking to change the structure coz that would mean messing around in the backend. I'm looking to solve this only for ie .. so even hack of some sort would do, as long as it works as intended.

So does any one have **solution** for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in the code:

- You have a `div` tag inside the `a` tag, which is not valid. Browsers will move the `div` element outside the `a` element.
- You have `class="feedback"` on the `div`, but you are using `.feedback_div` in the CSS, so the style won't apply.

When you use z-index, it applies to elememts on the same level, so you would apply it to the parent of the feedback elements as that is the one on the same level as the footer.

Comment: Hey thanks, ya i had some mistake in the code over here, i did a copy/paste of the css forgot to change the selectors sorry about that.

Comment: As for your solution you can see i'm applying z-index to #content-wrapper and #footer-wrapper. And abt the div being inside an <a> tag, i know its not semantically right, but i wanted to avoid a extra tag with(that i would get in) a div>a>span structure. And it work fine in all browsers even IE6 i dont see it being moved out of the <a> tag in the DOM

Comment: @ShalomSam: I see... the z-index should work, but having block elements inside inline elements definitely will cause you problems. Perhaps you are also experiencing the z-index bug that makes IE ignore the z-index if the parent element doesn't have a z-index: http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/

Comment: i tried giving its parent.. which in this case is body a z-index. But that didn't help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly, for IE6 you need to set `zoom: 1` for z-index to work correctly.

Comment: hmm .. but to which element do i apply this property??

Comment: i tried using zoom:1; for each use of z-index. But that doesn seem to help as well

Comment: Can you put the file(s) online somewhere and link to them? I might be able to be more helpful if I can see the complete result in a browser.

Comment: you'll see the feedback button on the right side(in all browser except IE6)